# Issues with two author instances of AEM of different versions in local

Tags: osgi, aem

We're upgrading to 6.1 from 5.6, I have 5.6 setup on port 4502, I changed the port on the jar for 6.1 from 4502 to 4512 and started up both at the same time. But seems like both http://localhost:4512/ and http://localhost:4502/ take me to AEM 6.1.

Are there other configs that need a change to have two versions up and running at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run multiple instances of AEM on your local computer. In fact, as an engineer you **should** definitely run at least one author instance and one publish instance on your local computer so that you can test your work in both environments before committing any code.

You can rename the jar to `cq-author-4502.jar`, `cq-publish-4503.jar` or replace your port number. By naming the file `cq-author-4512.jar` and running `java -jar cq-author-4512.jar`, the instance will start up on port `4512`.

If you want to start your instance using the `start` script, you need to update that script in the `/crx-quickstart/bin` directory. If you're on Linux or Mac update the `start` file. If you're on Windows update the `start.bat` file. Follow the instructions and replace `4502` with `4512` and `author` with `publish` if necessary. The `/crx-quickstart/bin` directory will be available after you run the jar file the first time.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to mention that port number can also be controlled by the `=p` or `-port` option with the `java` command. I feel it's better to use explicit variables instead of depending on filenames in case you're using variable controlling services (e.g. upstart script) to start/stop servers.

Comment: @Abhishek, definitely. We can also mention that sling runmodes can be set from the command line as well with `-Dsling.run.modes=publish,prod,foo`

Comment: cq-xxxx-4502.jar doesn't work (or rather it does - but only because 4502 is the default port). You need to put a p in front of the port number, cq-xxxx-p4502.jar

Comment: @gotofritz The "p" in the file name is optional. Both cq-publish-4503.jar and cq-publish-p4503.jar will start on port 4503.

Comment: @nateyolles Not for me, not sure whether it's a general thing or just OS X

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no useful and logical reason to have two instances that does not comply with author|publish configuration.

But you can start a... e.g. test|author configuration:

Open ../crx-quickstart/bin/start.sh or .bat

Change CQ_PORT=**4504** 
Change CQ_RUNMODE='**test**'

if [ -z "$CQ_PORT" ]; then
    CQ_PORT=4504
fi

if [ -z "$CQ_RUNMODE" ]; then
    CQ_RUNMODE='test'
fi

Open ../crx-quickstart/conf/sling.properties

Change author by test
sling.run.mode.install.options=**test**,publish|...

And start the instances in any order that you like.

Comment: You should leave the runmode as either `author` or `publish`. Note that this runmode cannot be changed after installation. If you want to add additional runmodes such as `test`, `local`, `stage`, `prod`, etc.., you can do that at any time. You should set that in the `sling.properties` as mentioned above, *however*, create a new line line for `sling.run.modes` such as `sling.run.modes=author,local,test` or `sling.run.modes=publish,prod,uswest` instead of `sling.run.mode.install.options`.

Comment: I disagree with your statement that "there is no useful and logical reason to have two instances that does not comply with author|publish configuration". I personally have dozens of local author instances for my various projects which have different CQ/AEM versions, different dependencies, various stages of content that may be mid transformation, etc... I think sooner or later you'll find a scenario where you might benefit from spinning up an additional local instance, whether permanent or temporary. Don't limit yourself during development, especially because it's so quick and easy.

Answer (score 1):

It might only be a caching issue in your browser.
When 6.1 has been started on 4502 and then you have an other AEM/CQ version on that port (stop 6.1, start 5.6.1 or something like that), your browser will sometimes show the cached 6.1 login screen or at least some of the 6.1 images that are cached. Press SHIFT-Reload and all should be well.